# How to make a wrong C program segfault consistantly?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Consider the two following lines of C :

```
int a[1] = {0};
a[1] = 0;
```

The second line makes a write access somewhere in the memory where it should not. Sometimes such programs will give a segfault during the execution, and sometimes not, depending on the environment I suppose, and maybe other things.

I wonder if there is a way to force, as much as possible, such programs to segfault (by compiling them in a special way for instance, or execute them in some virtual machine, I don't know).

This is for pedagogic purpose.

Comment: That's why this is called `Undefined Behavior`.

Comment: We need more info about your environment if you want something that consistently goes *boom*.

Comment: C doesn't require bounds-checks. Certain static analysers and compilation options (such as `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` of gcc) can do some checks but there's no standard or portable to way check all sorts of overflows.

Comment: `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);` should do the trick of seg faulting all the time

Comment: XY problem? Why do you need this?

Comment: @EdHeal: The request is to cause programs that have behavior not defined by the C standard to fault, not to generate a fault. In other words, they are not asking how to make a program crash; they are asking how to detect behavior not defined by the standard.

Comment: @n.m.: It would obviously be useful for finding bugs that go undetected because they happen not to cause segment faults or other glaring misbehaviors most of the time.

Comment: @EdHeal Your suggestion does indeed cause programs with memory access errors to segfault. What the OP wanted but forgot to specify was to *selectively* cause them to segfault. See https://xkcd.com/1217/, especially the title text.

Comment: Perhaps the poster whats to check that the program handles SIGSEGV - Could have a handler that would close down network connections etc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so the question is "how to find bugs", not "how to make a program crash".

Comment: @n.m.: Well, from a behavioral standpoint, you get a crash, you debug it, but it is not reproducible. Then, you identify the out of bounds bug. It may be reasonable in that case to ask what can be done to make such a bug consistently reproducible.

Comment: @jxh to debug stuff you use debugging tools like valgrind, app verifier, sanitizer runtimes etc

Comment: @n.m.: The newest tools are not always used in production environments. Upgrading tools can change the generated code into something that no longer exhibits the original problem.

Comment: On Linux it's pretty reliable to write to read-only memory, like a string constant: `char *p = "abc"; *p = 0;`

Comment: @jxh  Is it a constraint not to use any new tools? Where do you read this in the original question? I read *by compiling them in a special way for instance, or execute them in some virtual machine*.

Comment: @n.m.: The constraint is merely the nature of providing a widely applicable answer. Your solution is already presented by the currently most popular answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C language standard these kinds of accesses are undefined behaviour and the compiler and runtime are not obliged to make them segfault (though they obviously do sometimes).

For pedagogical purposes you can have a look at the address sanitizers in popular compilers like GCC (`-fsanitize=address` in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) and Clang (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

In simple terms these options cause the compiler to instrument memory accesses with extra logic to catch out-of-bounds memory accesses and produce a user-visible error (though not exacly a segfault message), allowing users to spot such errors and fix them.

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: “For pedagogical purposes”? It is useful for more than just pedagogy but for detecting bugs. You should regularly run your test suite with as many sanitizers active as you can.

Comment: Yes, of course :) Sanitizers are a very popular tool these days for good reason and I encourage their use in developing any software in C/C++.
I guess what I was getting at is that the OP should fix their out-of-bounds access, but if they want to experiment with detecting them, they can use sanitizers, or any of the other tools in this thread (valgrind etc)

Comment: Unfortunately the version of GCC we use where I work has some broken sanitizers which give false positives (yes, I am sure they are *false* positives), so I can’t turn them on yet. I hope to do that when we upgrade compilers; the issue has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind on Linux, stack guards for most compilers, debug options for you selected runtime (e.g. Application Verifier on Windows), there are plenty of options.

In your example the overflow is on the stack, which will always require the compiler to emit the appropriate guards. For dynamic memory allocations it's either up to the used C/C++ runtime library or a custom wrapper inside your application to catch this.

Tools like valgrind catch the heap based buffer overflow as they happen, as they actually execute the code in a VM.

Compiler assisted options work with canaries which are placed in front and back of the buffer, and which are typically checked again when the buffer is released. Options from the address sanitizer family may also add additional checks to all accesses on fields of a fixed size, but this won't work if raw pointers are involved.

Debug options for the runtime typically only provide a very rough granularity. Often they work by simply placing each allocation in a dedicated page in a non-continous address space. Accessing the gaps in between the pages then is an instant error. However only minor buffer overflows are typically not detected immediately.

Finally there is also static code analysis which all modern compilers support to some extent, which can easily detect at least trivial mistakes like the one in your example.

None of these options is able to catch all possible errors though. The C language gives you plenty of options to achieve undefined behavior which none of these tools can detect.